# How can I batch create more than one list?

Tags: calendar

I'd like to create a calendar for each item in an existing list. Aside from doing this manually, is there any batched way of doing this?

Update: I have a list of boardrooms with detailed information about the location, equipment available, contact info, etc., and I would like to attach a schedule (the calendars I'd like to create) to each of the boardrooms for booking purposes. I would then like to create a web part that allows working with each boardroom calendar.

Comment: I think the more important question is should you.  I'm sure it could be scripted in Powershell.

Comment: @PirateEric Why shouldn't I? (still learning sharepoint)

Comment: @nfw: What are your requirements for creating a calendar each time? Sounds to me like you'll end up with a LOT of calendars...

Comment: It's a poor architectural design and will give you some UI problems too.  Can you spell out what the requirement and goal is in a bit more detail and I'm sure we can guide you on a proper path.

Comment: @PirateEric @Kit Menke I have updated my original question with more information on my issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your updated requirements, multiple calendars aren't really necessary.  You can use 1 calendar with additional metadata (like lookup columns to other lists) to pull off what you need.  When users fill out a calendar item, they fill out the metadata.  You can use this metadata to create additional views to slice the data to show bookings for a particular boardroom to show it's availability or what ever you'd need.

Comment: Thanks so much, that makes a ton of sense. Can you point me in the right direction on how I would find information on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

First of all - you can definitely do this using PowerShell.  Question: Are you going to want future calendar lists to be automatically provisioned upon creation of an SP List Item?  If so, there's a two step approach here - first, you'll need PowerShell code to create lists based on the current items.

Second thing you'll need is some sort of automated means of creating new calendar lists when new list items are created.  Depending on your version of SharePoint, you could perhaps customize your list with InfoPath - adding some logic to use a web service call to lists.asmx to provision a new list when a list item is added.

Comment: I believe the list is relatively final, and further list additions would be rare, so updating them manually upon new additions would not be an issue. Thanks for the InfoPath suggestion, I'll look into what it is capable of and see if it can help me out.

Comment: You're welcome, InfoPath with SP2010 provides some great integration options.  Definitely look into it. :)

Also, I agree with the solution posted by PirateEric based on your updated requirements.  Good luck!